# Can my app choose the biometric type a user uses to authenticate?

Tags: android, biometrics, android-biometric

If the user has an Android device with both biometrics features, face and fingerprint, can my app choose which one to use?

Along with my question:

- Can both features be active at the same time?
- Is there any way to know which one is activated?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you can activate two options from phone settings, but you can't decide which one will be challenged to user
2. There is no mean of knowing this type of information for now, an issue had been opened last year to ask for it (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111315641