# Flutter - local_auth - Unable to choose type of biometric to use

Tags: flutter, authentication, plugins, biometrics

I saw that it is impossible to choose the type of biometric to use in the local_auth plugin in flutter. ([Can my app choose the biometric type a user uses to authenticate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67131589/can-my-app-choose-the-biometric-type-a-user-uses-to-authenticate))

I would like to know if it is the same even under native android or IOS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Developers do not yet develop it. The issue is still open.
There are restrictions from the OS end.

The android biometric fingerprint only library is merged with common biometrics with both face and touch.

If you want then you need to find a native solution.